# Загрузка файлов webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Здравствуйте! Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в создании приложений под андроид. Только начал.

Я собрал `webview` приложение для своего веб сайта, но никак не могу понять почему не появляется окно выбора файлов при нажатии на кнопку - **Выбрать файл**

При этом комплиятор не выдает никаких ошибок. Выбор файла просто не работает.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mywebview;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //webview
        mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://m.samods.ru/");
        mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            }

        });
        //setContentView(mywebview);



        //swipe refresh
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mywebview.loadUrl("javascript: loc = location.href; location.href=loc");
                //mywebview.loadUrl("javascript: window.location.reload();");
            }
        });

        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
                if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });

    }



    //back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            //mywebview.goBack();
            mywebview.loadUrl("javascript: popstate();");

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Удалось ли найти решение? У меня работает только на андроид 5 и выше. Всякие хаки с добавлением перегруженных методов onShowFileChooser в WebChromeClient не работают. Можно ли как-то добиться, чтобы в 4.4 тоже работало? targetSDK 30

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
 mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 mywebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

По-моему тут что-то кардинально не так.

По идее вы должны реализовать хэндлер [onShowFileChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams), в котором надо вызывать `openFileChooser()`

в свою очередь `onShowFileChooser()` срабатывает когда на веб странице нажимается HTML форма с типом "file"